# TeamSpeak 3 on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, teamspeak

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I know nothing about this system. My question is, why can't I open TeamSpeak 3? I have no idea how to open this file. On Windows 7 this is pretty easy but on Ubuntu I get the message: `please select program to opening file`. What program do I use to open this file?

Answer (score 26):

[Downloaded TeamSpeak 3 file](http://www.teamspeak.com/downloads) needs to be run - its an **installer script**.

### 1. Allow Execution of Installer

You have to change its **permissions** first, allowing it to be **executed**. You can do it in shell (`chmod +x TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.16.run`) or selecting *Properties* of the file, and allowing it like this:

[image: Allow execution file as program]

### 2. Run the Installer

Open your Terminal (you can press default shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and go to directory where the file is located, eg:

```
cd Downloads
```

And run the installer, eg. like this:

```
./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.0.16.run
```

### 3. Keep System Clean

TeamSpeak will be installed in current directory, and its probably a good idea to **move it somewhere** - `/opt` is good place to keep **additional software** like this (which didn`t come from "normal" Ubuntu packages):

```
sudo mv TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64 /opt/
```

### 4. Run TeamSpeak

To **run** installed TeamSpeak enter:

```
/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
```

### 5. Create Launcher

You can permanently create a **Launcher**, for yourself:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/TeamSpeak3.desktop
```

...or for all users on your system like this:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/TeamSpeak3.desktop
```

Put a content to this Launcher like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TeamSpeak 3
Comment=TeamSpeak 3 VoIP Communicator
Exec=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;Application;
Icon=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/styles/default/logo-128x128.png
```

---

Remember to **replace file and directory names** accordingly to TeamSpeak version (here 3.0.16) and target **architecture** (here amd64).

*(The default Icon is somewhat too pale - you can find another icon if you wish)*

Comment: What are the recommended permissions to set with the /opt installation, (rather than installing in the user's home directory ~/ )?  Will teamspeak automagically write server info to the user's home folders?  Or, is there an option for Teamspeak to use a shared configuration and pull servers from /etc/, or other location?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that in the future, after following this guide, you need to update teamspeak (You have already created the desktop entry) Do only steps 1 - 3 and your desktop entry should still point to the right place. :) PS. You may need to remove the existing version `sudo rm -r /opt/TeamSpeak*` '*' = wildcard (be careful with this) '-r' = recursive (for removing entire directories).

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment yet I'll post this as an answer.
@madneon 's answer works but you need to put "" around the path in Exec otherwise it won't work (tested on Ubuntu 16.04)
Seeing how this is one of the first results when searching for this 'problem'

To be clear:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TeamSpeak 3
Comment=TeamSpeak 3 VoIP Communicator
--Exec="/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh"--
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;Application;
Icon=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/styles/default/logo-128x128.png
```